# How do I run React-Native-Navigation v2 Playground from the cloned repo on my Windows?

Tags: android-studio, react-native, adb, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have cloned Wix RNN2 repo [Branch v2] and I am not sure how to run ***playground*** on my emulator.

If I just run `npm run start`, I get this error:

```
> rm -rf ./lib/dist && tsc
'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Windows cannot recognize that command because its linux.

I have tried running the app from Android Studio, and on my emulator, it says:

**Unable to load scripts from assets 'index.android.bundle** - which is because I don't have Metro Bundler making a bundle for me.

Anyways, what is the right way to run this example by Wix RNN2?

*I have VSCode, Expo, Android Studio and my android build has no errors for the Android project.*

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps:

1) `git clone https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation.git`

2) `cd react-native-navigation`

3) `npm install`

4) `npm start`

5) `open xcode`

Comment: How about android, please? There is no xcode on windows :)